# Unpack integer or float - binary search?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How do you unpack an `integer (1111)` so it returns a 3-elements tuple containing lists? The first element of the tuple should be a list containing the leading digit. The second should be a list of digits that follow the leading digit and precede the decimal. The third element should follow the decimal point.

Example 1:

```
>>> unpackNumber ( 1111 )

( [ 1] , [1 , 1, 1 ], [ ] )
```

Example 2:

```
>>>unpackNumber(2.)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, I couldn't think how it's related to binary search though.

Using regex is one option:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(^\d)(\d*)\.?(\d*)$', '123.4')
[('1', '23', '4')]
>>> re.findall(r'(^\d)(\d*)\.?(\d*)$', '123.')
[('1', '23', '')]
```

To convert the elements further to lists of integers is relatively simple, e.g:

```
>>> [int(d) for d in list('23')]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: The output that I am looking for is a series of a list of strings that make up a three-element tuple.
                                      ( [2], [3], [] ) 

is what should be returned if you input unpackNumber(23)

Comment: Did you read my answer? I'm not giving you the whole code, but it's relatively straightforward to do the rest of the job, that part is left to you on purpose, how else could you learn?